# Save objects in a list and draw them in windows forms using F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I'm currently learning F# from a C# background and I did a similar project to this when I learned C# which is why I'm attempting this same thing in F#, what I want to create is a very simple 2D graphics editor using windows forms and F# and I ran into some troubble.

The way I'm doing it (as I did in C#) is to create different shapes by pressing menu buttons, for instance I press "square" in my menu and I want the program to create a square object from a predefined type, add it to a list of all the other square objects and then re-draw the form (invalidate).

Sounds rather simple for an experienced F# programmer I assume, anyway here's what I have.

I have my type square

```
type square(x : float, y : float) =
    let length = 10
    let height = 10
```

and I have my menu and form and everything

```
let form =
    let temp = new Form(Width= 900, Height = 500,Text="Graphics Editor")
    temp.BackColor <- Color.White
    let menu = new MenuStrip()
    let create = new ToolStripDropDownButton("Create")  // Menu
    ignore(menu.Items.Add(create))
    let square = create.DropDownItems.Add("Square")
```

and an empty list of squares

```
let listOfSquares = []
```

Now to the problem.

I want to create a square, then add it to the empty list of squares when I click the menu option Square. Something like this

```
square.Click.Add(fun _ -> let sq = circle(3.0, 4.0), sq :: listOfSquares |> ignore) //I know the syntax here is off but I hope it shows what I'm tryng to acomplish
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mutate the list try using `ResizeArray`. F# lists are immutable.

```
let listOfSquares = ResizeArray()

square.Click.Add(fun _ -> listOfSquares.Add(circle(3.0, 4.0)))
```

Comment: Okay, didn't know that thanks. Allthough I'm getting an error under "circle" saying the value isn't a function and cannot be applied when doing this, not really sure why.. any ideas?

Comment: I'd have to see the definition of `circle` to know.

Comment: Oh my bad, I'ts the exact same as square, nothing special